# Push notification not receiving android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

In my application I try to receive notification from server, but I don't receive messages. Some time I have this exception(but not all time):

```
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo﹕ Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
E/com.parse.PushService﹕ Tried to use push, but this app is not configured for push due to: Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to support either GCM or PPNS for push (or both). To enable GCM support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
To enable PPNS support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But I receive it not all time. Code:
Application:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, appKey, clientKey);
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
}
```

All time SaveCallback return "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel." even if I get exception which I mentioned above.

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.parsepushnotification" >

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <permission
    android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".TestApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.PushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activit);
  }
}
```

PushReceiver.java

```
public class PushReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private static final String TAG = "PushReceiver";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Message accept");
     showNotification();

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As for your code you should divide receiving part and Notification UI part. I mean UI part isn't related to the question

but also about UI part 

line

    manager.notify(1, builder.build());

id An identifier for this notification unique within your application. 

from the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int, android.app.Notification)

So ID must be unique

Comment: Does you device support GCM at all? You can test that by [Push Notificaiton Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.firstrowria.pushnotificationtester&hl=en) Why do you need both ways to receive messages: parse and GCM?

Comment: @gio I use only one method to receive message. All my code described above. Also in https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/Android descrides that: "The Parse library provides push notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) if possible"

Comment: @dima did you test Push notification at your device via provided link above?

Comment: @gio No, I tried send by parse.com . Also several day ago I update Parse to 1.8.1 and it fixed my problem but today I have this problem again

Comment: not sure if you should use the [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: @user2450263 No, it didn't help. Receiver doesn't receive message

Comment: Appreciate your effort to try that, another thing, the receiver and service for `<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">` should be your package name, or just `<service android:name=".PushService" />
    <receiver android:name=".ParseBroadcastReceiver">` should also do, or is that not the case when using Parse(?)

Comment: @Orion Sorry, I think I didn't understand you, there was <permission android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
in my manifest

Comment: @user2450263 I can't use PushService and ParseBrodcastReceiver with my package, because they inside com.parse package. In user guide said that need change package only in category inside receiver tag (in my manifest it inside <receiver android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.PushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> ) https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/new

Comment: `<receiver android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.PushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">` in your manifest, is mentioned on [Quick Start | Parse](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/new) as `<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">`, that could be causing the problem with identification from Parse's side

Comment: @user2450263 you are right. I found answer thanks to your comment. android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver have to stay com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver and custom receiver write instead  <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
Post it in answer and I will approve your answer

Comment: glad it helped, these things can be quite time consuming and sometimes...frustrating

Comment: I have the same problem here, not registering the deviceToken on my debug flavor app. And I'm pretty sure it is due to a missconfiguration on my manifest. Could you take a look @user2450263 on my posted question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866724/parse-does-not-update-devicetoken-on-debug-app-when-saving-current-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manifest in question,
`<receiver android:name="com.test.parsepushnotification.PushReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">`  ,
is mentioned on [Quick Start | Parse](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/new) as
 `<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">`,
 the changed package name can cause the problem with identification from Parse's side.

Thanks for letting us know it worked.